# Two tables above each other where the visual width for both is the larger of the two

Tags: html, alignment, width, css-tables

I have two tables that I'd like to stack one on top of the other so that visually they appear to be one entity - the width of both should be equal.

For arguments sake, lets say the top table has 8 columns and the bottom will have 3 columns. How do I get it so that the bottom table occupies the same visual width as the top table?

The reason I want this is because the top table is loaded with radio buttons and checkbox items, and the lower table will always have only one row consisting of a cancel button, a quantity field and an OK button. I have dozens of different top tables of various widths but I want to code only one of the bottom table and with Javascript haul in one of the top tables and put the lower table below it so it occupies the same width as that top table.

I'm stuck on the html and / or CSS to get the widths the same. I'm not adamant about the lower thing being a table. If there's a solution that will give me those 3 fields nicely centered within the width of the top table, that's great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/FBqnJ/3/)**

CSS

```
table {
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.table1 td {
    border:1px solid red;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}
.table2 td {
    height:50px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

HTML

```
<table class="table1">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</table>
<table class="table2">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
var width = function () {
    $('.table2').width($('.table1').width());
};

$(document).ready(width);
$(window).resize(width);
```

**If you prefer pure JavaScript:**

**[Working Example2](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/FBqnJ/4/)**

```
function tablewidth() {
    var table1 = document.getElementById('table1'),
        style = window.getComputedStyle(table1),
        width = style.getPropertyValue('width'),
        border = style.getPropertyValue('border-left-width'),
        w = parseInt(width, 10) + parseInt(border, 10) * 2 + 'px';

    document.getElementById('table2').style.width = w;
}
window.onresize = tablewidth;
window.onload = tablewidth;
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion. It stretches the top table and then does put the bottom table below it to occupy the whole space. What I'm after is to leave the top table alone - allow it to naturally take up as much width as it needs and then match the bottom width to whatever that is.

Comment: By trial and error, I came up with a solution is pure HTML/CSS. I wrapped a div around the 2 tables and just set the CSS width of each table to 100%.  Your latest example is interesting in showing how to go about it in JS.

Comment: @BillGradwohl that's effectively the same as my first answer... The only difference being that you used a div rather than the body

Comment: @BillGradwohl I edited to another solution because you said "What I'm after is to leave the top table alone - allow it to naturally take up as much width as it needs and then match the bottom width to whatever that is."

Comment: You're example gave me the idea. Using the div made all the difference.  Thank You

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get it so that the bottom table occupies the same visual width as the top table?

What's wrong with defining the same width to them? Can't you do `table { width: 500px; }`?

Comment: I don't know what the width is. It varies as the tables shrink and grows in width depending on the data. I don't want to state a width, I want to allow the top table to rule what the bottom width will be.

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping them into a div like so:

```
<div id="table_wrapper">
    <table>...
    <table>....
</div>
```

Assign a width to the div via CSS, for example 80%, and set the table's width to 100%. That should strech them to the maximum width defined for the outer div.